# Cannot Get Permission Prompt

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

**Workaround posted as an answer below, I have concluded this is an iOS 8-8.1+ bug that to my knowledge has not been fixed.**

Original post:

Im at a loss, this was working before but after many changes and updates to my app it is no longer working, I'm not 100% sure if it is due to iOS 8 or my app, as this app has been a WIP for a very long time.

I am not getting prompted if I (the user) want to allow notifications from my app.

Update:  I tested my app on a another device (iPhone 5, iOS 8.1.2) and it successfully asked for permission, while it still does not work on my device (iPhone 6+, iOS 8.0).

(Edit for clarity: The test was the first ever install of the app on the iPhone 5, iOS 8.1.2, and the issue still existed on a reinstall on the iPhone 5 as stated in update 2.)

Update 2: When I uninstalled the app from the second device (Update1: iPhone 5) it never prompted me again for notification permission, but it still worked, and the log also showed that the permissions where set. But it still prompted the user for the location permission.

The error:

```
2014-12-17 09:49:51.852 Attempting to schedule a local notification  <UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0x170344620>{fire date = (null), time zone = (null), repeat interval = 0, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = Wednesday, December 17, 2014 at 9:49:51 AM Central Standard Time, user info = (null)} with an alert but haven't received permission from the user to display alerts

2014-12-17 09:49:51.853 Attempting to schedule a local notification <UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0x170344620>{fire date = (null), time zone = (null), repeat interval = 0, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = Wednesday, December 17, 2014 at 9:49:51 AM Central Standard Time, user info = (null)} with a sound but haven't received permission from the user to play sounds
```

The code that I had that used to work fine:

AppDelegate : didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0) {
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
}
```

The code that I have since tried:

```
if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
}

[application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
```

&

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0) {
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
}
```

&

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
{
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge
                                                                                         |UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound|UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];

    NSLog(@"current notifications : %@", [application currentUserNotificationSettings]);

    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

I have tried all of those separately and together in both AppDelegate : didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and in FirstViewController on an IBAction (with replacing application with [UIApplication sharedApplication] of course)

After I try and set the permissions I try checking in an NSLog:

```
NSLog(@"current notifications : %@", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings]);
```

NSLog:

```
current notifications : <UIUserNotificationSettings: 0x170435ee0; types: (none);>
```

In my app I ask for permission for using their location just fine and have tried asking for Notification Permission before and after asking for their location and it made no difference.

Code for location permission that works fine..

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
if([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
```

Comment: It sounds like what you're saying is that this was a bug in iOS 8 and is fixed in iOS 8.1. That's the difference between where it doesn't work and where it does work, right?

Comment: I don't think its a bug between permissions working or not, as much as it is the prompt of the notification permission not clearing after a user installs the app. Basically making it permanent for the app.

Comment: Exactly. But in iOS 8.1 that is fixed?

Comment: No, its not.. On any iOS 8 (8.0 or 8.1) it is not prompting for a notification permission after a user deletes and reinstalls an app.

Comment: Which can go unnoticed when a developer allows the app to get the notification in their first test, they will never get prompted again unless its a new device entirely, so in my case I must have said to not allow the notification in the beginning which now I cannot get reprompted.

Comment: How about if you do Settings > General > Reset > Location & Privacy?

Comment: "Which can go unnoticed when a developer allows the app to get the notification in their first test" Correct-a-mundo. That is why in my book I advise registering both in `didFinishLaunching` and in `applicationWillEnterForeground`. See my example code here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch13p630localNotification/ch26p899localNotification/AppDelegate.swift

Comment: That will not adjust notification settings, I have found a workaround in the device settings. Typing my instructions now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Cool-o-rama. You should enter your solution as an answer and accept it!

Comment: Will do! As per your book, I would recommend people to make a view that gets displayed after it loads the first view controller when its a new install, that says something about what or why your asking to avoid a 'Whats this?' question by the user and then they regrettably say no to something. Just a thought.

Comment: How did so few ppl notice this issue? Anyway, I guess you would need to check permissions in your code, and if permissions aren't granted then make pop-up that asks the user to go to settings->..........

Comment: @DevilInDisguise Is this issue still happening? I haven't checked to see if it has been patched or not.

Comment: @Mbarton Im using 8.1and have this issue. I haven't got it out to tester yet who's running ios9, so can't tell yet. Seems the OP said his iPhone 5 8.1.2 was asking successfully.

Comment: @DevilInDisguise The only reason why my (I'm OP) iPhone 5 8.1.2 prompted was because it was fresh, never installed before, on the device. It later would not reprompt on the iPhone 5 when reinstalling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have concluded after many tests with many devices that this issue with iOS 8 its self. After my testing I have not noticed this problem to be fixed in either 8.0 or 8.1. I have not tested all the versions as so it is unknown if this bug is still occurring. I have found a workaround and instructions are below.

Workaround:

What the user (aka you) can do to fix the problem of not prompting for permission to display UILocalNotifications is allow the app to display the Notifications manually.

Note: *** Every time you uninstall and reinstall the application you will need to repeat this. ***

Go to:

```
Settings > Notifications
```

And find your app in the list and select it. Their will be settings for what the app is allowed and isn't allowed to do with Notifications. Make sure the toggle "Allow Notifications" is toggled on, and the other settings are as desired.

Warning for developers:

This bug can go unnoticed when a developer allows the app to get the notification in your first test, you will never get prompted again unless it's a new device entirely, so if a develeper were to not allow the notification when apple prompts in the beginning you cannot get reprompted. The same bug still applies whether or not you approve the permission or deny, you will only get prompted once on a device, a delete and reinstall will not reprompt you.

In my situation:

During my testing I must have pressed the don't allow, for the Notification permission and with the bug in iOS 8 it stuck as permanent and would not prompt me again for permission. I then went to the Settings > Notifications and noticed that my app was listed under "DO NOT INCLUDE", I then selected my app from the settings and enabled them.

Answer (score 2):

The app should always check the permission status:

```
let settings = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()
```

When the app realizes that we have no permissions, it should put up an alert offering to *take* the user *directly* to the right spot in the Settings app. If the user accepts, then run this code (this is Swift but I'm sure you can translate):

```
let url = NSURL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
```

That's a new iOS 8 feature.